# Linq to find Firstname and Lastname

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can anyone suggest how I can write a linq query to find users in a table with a single search field?

Users can enter 'Name' in a single text box in the UI (e.g. 'Joe Bloggs', or 'Will Green Smith'). I want to split that value up and search both Firstname and Lastname columns using 'like' functionality. So something like this:

```
select * from Users 
where 
Firstname like '%Joe%' or Firstname like '%Bloggs%' 
or Firstname like '%Will%' or Firstname like '%Green%' 
or Firstname like '%Smith%' 
or Lastname like '%Joe%' or Lastname like '%Bloggs%' 
or Lastname like '%Will%' or Lastname like '%Green%' 
or Lastname  like '%Smith%'
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same effect in linq?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? It's not for us to just write your code for you on demand. If you want to use LINQ, learn how to use LINQ. Do what you think needs to be done and then, if it doesn't work, you have a question to ask us about.

Comment: I do want to help and I did so, by telling you want you need to do to write a good question. This site is basically self-policing and if no one tells you what you're doing wrong, you'll continue to make the same mistakes. You may then not get the help you want and wonder why. The fact that someone doesn't do what you want them to doesn't mean that they have necessarily not helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build up an expression during runtime. I assume you have the following class:

```
class User
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

As an input, you might have an array like this:

```
var searchPattern = new string[] { "Joe", "Bloggs", "Will", "Green", "Smith" };
```

Then we create two expressions for each element of the searchPattern array. The first expression will compare the string with the `FirstName` property, the second expression will compare the string with the `LastName` property:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
var expressions = searchPattern.Select(x => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "FirstName"), Expression.Constant(x, typeof(string))))
            .Concat(searchPattern.Select(x => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "LastName"), Expression.Constant(x, typeof(string)))));
```

All these expressions are then combined with `OrElse` to a big expression:

```
var aggregated = expressions.Aggregate((x,y) => Expression.OrElse(x,y));
```

We have to convert this `BinaryExpression` to an `Expression<Func<User,bool>>` if we want to use it with LINQ:

```
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<User,bool>>(aggregated, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
```

In Entity Framework, this can be used directly:

```
var result = context.Users.Where(expression);
```

If you use Linq2Objects, you have to create a function first:

```
var result = users.Where(expression.Compile());
```

The code would create a SQL query with `Firstname = 'Joe'` instead `Firstname like '%Joe%'`. If you want to use like, the expressions will become a bit more complicated. You will have to call the `Contains` method of the string class. This will lead to the following expressions (which have to be aggregated as above):

```
var expressions = searchPattern.Select(x => Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "FirstName"), typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(x, typeof(string)) }), Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool))))
            .Concat(searchPattern.Select(x => Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "LastName"), typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(x, typeof(string)) }), Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool)))));
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cM0tz0

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. It looks exactly what I need. Unfortunately it throws an AmbiguousMatchException error when I run it under .NET 7 but I think it's on the right path...

Comment: found the problem. Need to use typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), then everything works in .NET 7. Thanks again for providing such a clear answer!